# I want to get time difference between two time in milisecond

Tags: java, android, time

I want to get time difference between two times in milliseconds.

**Note**

If the difference is above half a second they return 1000 millisecond, so how to get
  proper millisecond like if difference of half second to get 500 millisecond

Difference between two times is half second then my code returns
 **1000 milliseconds** that means **1 Second** but actually its **0.5 Second** so how get **500
 milliseconds** if difference is half second

```
    Date Date1 = sdf.parse(lastTime);
    Date Date2 = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    long millie = Date2.getTime() - Date1.getTime();
```

Comment: why still use **outdated** Date still instead of newly introduced **LocateDate** in Java 8?

Comment: Simplifying your example to: 
        Date Date1 = new Date(1000);
        Date Date2 = new Date(1500);
        long millie = Date2.getTime() - Date1.getTime();
        System.out.println(millie);

outputs 500

Comment: Trying to **round** the time millis or just calculate the time difference?

Comment: What's the purpose of this line: `Date Date2 = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));`? I think you can optimise it to `Date Date2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` does not include milliseconds by default. So

```
sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

does not output the milliseconds and everything is rounded to seconds.

Define a custom date format including milliseconds like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `java8` then try with this:

```
LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.of(2018,07,31,12,1);
long diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startTime,LocalDateTime.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find difference between two date in millisecond,second,minutes and hours by calling following method, you can change method by your requirements.

```
    public void printDifference(Date startDate) {

        Date endDate=new Date();

        long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime(); //Different in miliseconds

        System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
        System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
        System.out.println("different : " + different);
        int months=0,year=0;
        long secondsInMilli = 1000;
        long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
        long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
        long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

        long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
        different = different % daysInMilli;

        long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
        different = different % hoursInMilli;

        long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
        different = different % minutesInMilli;

        long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try my below code:

```
         Date date = null;
         String value="3 Feb 2018 13:01:41 GMT";
         DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
         formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
         try {
            date = formatter.parse(value);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Prints the date in the CET timezone
        System.out.println("ConvertTime from serverformat before settimezone ::" + formatter.format(date));
        // Set the formatter to use a different timezone
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        // Prints the date in the IST timezone
        System.out.println("ConvertTime from serverformat after settimezone ::" + formatter.format(date));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateobj = new Date();
        System.out.println("Current date and time before settimezone:: " + df.format(dateobj));
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println("current format after settimezone ::" + df.format(dateobj));
        int difference = 0;
        int diff_Minutes=0;
        int diff_Seconds=0;
        System.out.println("Default values::" + difference+"   "+diff_Minutes+"   "+diff_Seconds);
        difference = (int) (dateobj.getTime() - date.getTime());
        diff_Minutes = difference / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        diff_Seconds = difference / 1000 % 60;
```

here i am converting current time from server time . here u have to take difference between two times. i hope you understand above code.let me know is it ok or not...
Thanks.